# Hibernate Criteria Example query

Tags: hibernate, persistence, hibernate-criteria

I have a problem with Hibernate Example queries. How can i do join query with using Hibernate Example queries. Here is what I want to do;

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.setFood(myFoodObject); // Food is another entity that has reference to Cat class.
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.add( Example.create(cat) )
.list();
```

my Food class;

```
public class Food { 
.....
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "food", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Cat> catList;
}
```

my Cat class;

```
public class Cat{
.....
@JoinColumn(name = "food", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Food food;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for Example queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples) says:

> Version properties, identifiers **and associations** are ignored.

(emphasis mine)